# I want to send key-pair values in soap web Service using ksoap2 library in android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

I want to send key-pair values in soap web Service using ksoap2 library in android. For this I used the below code

```
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
hashtable.put("is_report", false);
hashtable.put("r_how", 1); 
request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHODE);
request.addProperty("params",hashtable);
SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 

 HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("xxxxxxxxxx"); 
 env.setOutputSoapObject(request)
(new MarshalHashtable()).register(env); 
 androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
 Object product_update = enve.getResponse();
 Log.d("Response "," "+product_update.toString());
```

I got the response from server as 'true' but the data does not updated. What is wrong in the code?

Comment: I got the answer for this one, We have to use a KVMSerializable class to send the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this: [Adding an array of complex objects to the request](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Adding_an_array_of_complex_objects_to_the_request).

Comment: I got the answer already, Anyway Thanks for replay. Can you please look the following and give me a solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951805/call-magento-soap-v2-api-from-android-with-complex-datatype